# Cant mange to install a package in python

Tags: python-2.7

Im following an extremely basic tutorial of how to install something in python. 
The tutorial basically just says;

1. open cmd
2. cd C:\Users\fmromss\Downloads\XlsxWriter-0.8.9
3. python setup.py install

But I keep getting error messages saying python is not a internal nor external command..

I have just started using python so my knowledge and skills are very limited but cmon! How does this not work?

Comment: Check if Python is in your PATH variable

Comment: I can't answer your question since I don't work in Windows anymore, but I can recommend installing Anaconda in WIndows. Anaconda is a high performance distribution of Python and R and includes over 100 of the most popular Python, R and Scala packages for data science. For me it worked like a charm and installing packages newer posed any problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I had a problem similar to this one and my friend managed to find a solution to it. Open Python and type out:

```
import subprocess, sys
def install(package):
 subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
```

Then leave a line and do:

```
install('PACKAGE')
```

Replace `PACKAGE` with the name of the package you want to install.

**Note:** This only works for packages on pip.